# try-catch doesn't work with XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, try-catch

I am trying to use the `try-catch` statements to handle the errors from `XMLHTTPRequest`, like below:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', someurl, true);
try{
    xhr.sendMultipart(object);
}
catch(err){
    error_handle_function();
}
```

When there was a 401 error thrown by `xhr.sendMultipart`, the `error_handle_function` was not called. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think you can't catch server errors that way. you should be checking the status code instead:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4){   //if complete
        if(xhr.status === 200){  //check if "OK" (200)
            //success
        } else {
            error_handle_function(); //otherwise, some other code was returned
        }
    } 
}
xhr.open('POST', someurl, true);
xhr.sendMultipart(object);
```

Comment: If you install [Web Server Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-notifier/najdkmbedaehkepolllmpdfccdgooajh) on Chrome and try to go to play.google.com, for instance, you'll see a regular 404 error I can't prevent even checking status code before. Any idea on why?

Comment: On line 3, where does the xmlhttp object come from?

Comment: Chrome still throws error in console and then calls handler.

Answer (score 6):

> When there was a 401 error thrown by xhr.sendMultipart

It was not thrown.  It was returned asynchronously.

That means that this code finishes running before the response arrives.  That's what the `true` in your `open` call means.

You need to register an `onReadyStateChange` handler and handle error responses there.