# How to avoid XMLHttpRequest.send() error to be displayed in the console?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is not a duplicate of [try-catch doesn't work with XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458632/try-catch-doesnt-work-with-xmlhttprequest) I no longer want to catch the error, I want to prevent the error message to be displayed in the console.

---

I wrote the following code for Ajax request in JavaScript:

```
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

try {

     request.onreadystatechange = success;
     request.open('POST', 'https://urlthatdonotexist.com', true);
     request.send('key=value');
}
catch(e) 
{ 
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'error';
    console.log (e);
}



function success()
{

    if (request.readyState != 4) return;
    if (request.status != 200) { document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'error'; return; }
    document.getElementById('output').textContent = 'success';  
    console.log (request);
}
```

As you can see, the URL does not exists and the following error is generated:

```
(index):38 POST https://urlthatdonotexist.com/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

which is the expected behavior. But as you can see, I expected the error to be catch by the `try...catch`, and it is not the case as mentionned in this question:

[try-catch doesn't work with XMLHTTPRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458632/try-catch-doesnt-work-with-xmlhttprequest)

How to prevent the error to be displayed in the console?

I made a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/4mvdn1jf/13/)

Comment: _"the error should be catch by the `try...catch`"_ - Why? `.open()` and `.send()` work exactly as expected. The "error" is just your interpretation of the result of the call. But that's nothing that would require the JavaScript engine to abort a script for.

Comment: @Ivar, no, I edited my question.

Comment: @Ivar, I just updated the code and Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/4mvdn1jf/13/

Comment: @Fifi Your fiddle shows "error" for me.

Comment: @Ivar, Yes, I updated the JSFiddle, but have a look at the console. The error is displayed.

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear to me that the ultimate goal was to prevent the error from showing up. I'm afraid that you can't prevent that. That error is logged by the browser when it detect a `4xx`/`5xx` response and it doesn't provide a way to suppress that programmatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372271/jquery-ajax-how-to-prevent-404-errors-spam-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: OK, this time, this is a duplicate.!

Comment: Well, I retracted my last vote and you can only vote once on a question. But I believe that you should be able to close vote it yourself, as you have more than 250 reputation. :)

Comment: Already done ;-)